# All my iMessages were deleted

Tags: messages

My iPod Touch ran out of battery and died for a short time. When I plugged it back in and it turned back on, all of my conversations on iMessage had been deleted. I still have the contacts but all of my texts and messages were gone. Why did this happen and is there any way to get my messages back?

Comment: Restore from a backup

Answer (score 1):

#### Reboot your phone.

I discovered a solution for this one accidentally, after I encountered this bug a couple of days ago. I turned my phone off for a time, and then back on again - when it was turned back on, the list of messages was fully restored. I think that this might be because only the listing of messages was made inaccessible, and the messages themselves weren't deleted - I noticed that when I was texted by someone who I'd received messages from in the past, the message history was properly displayed once I opened the text conversation with them.

It's possible that the simplicity of fixing this issue is why Apple hasn't patched the bug in the 5+ years it's been known about.

Answer (score -1):

There ( sorry ) Is no possible way to get your messages back. The reason is is probably because your iPod was corrupt or not up to date. Simply contact an apple store and turn your Pod in, and they should give u a replacement while they check for a virus. Other reason may be because someone sent u a corrupt picture, long text, or virus text while your phone was off. Update your iPhone ( Software update ) and it'll never happen again.

Comment: Please provide a source for your claims. To my knowledge iMessages are stored on iCloud servers. What viruses are there for iPods?